# Exception on Converting string into json format

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert this string

```
{result:
 {data: 
﻿[
{id:6_99_First_99_Copy,name:First Copy},
{id:2_99_Third_99_View,name:Third View},
{id:9_99_test1,name:test1},
{id:3_99_Fourth_99_View,name:Fourth View},

{id:8_99_test,name:test}]
,status: success,message: Success.}}
```

to json format.

My code :

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(is,
                                                Charset.forName("utf-8")), 8);
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                String line = null;
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                                }
                                is.close();
                                //xmlString = sb.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
                                xmlString = sb.toString().replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
                                 newStr = xmlString.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\");


                                Log.w("Response Data: ", "" + newStr);
```

I have searched a lot but nothing is going to work , i tried to replace inverted commas as suggested in many post my output of above code is :

output :

```
{result: {data: ﻿[{\"id\":\"6_99_First_99_Copy\",\"name\":\"First Copy\"},{\"id\":\"2_99_Third_99_View\",\"name\":\"Third View\"},{\"id\":\"9_99_test1\",\"name\":\"test1\"},{\"id\":\"3_99_Fourth_99_View\",\"name\":\"Fourth View\"},{\"id\":\"4_99_Fifth_99_View\",\"name\":\"Fifth View\"},{\"id\":\"5_99_Sixth_99_View\",\"name\":\"Sixth View\"},{\"id\":\"7_99_First_99_View\",\"name\":\"First View\"},{\"id\":\"7_99_First_99_Copy\",\"name\":\"First Copy\"},{\"id\":\"1_99_Secon_99_View\",\"name\":\"Secon View\"},{\"id\":\"8_99_test\",\"name\":\"test\"}]
,status: success,message: Success.}}
```

I am getting this exception.

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 18 of {result: {data: ﻿[{id:6_99_First_99_Copy,name:First Copy},
```

Where I am doing wrong ?
Suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you better first validate your JSON string, Simply first log your converted string(JSON) and validate it, You may use this [Json Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Once you are sure that your are resultant string in a correct JSON, then try the above.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think your returning JSON string is not a valid one. Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for validating format. it will show the correct format and show errors if any.